# problems with instagram API and jquery: can't show items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

What am I doing wrong in this code? Thanks for ry time!

This is the code in action
http://jsbin.com/aMiQEsA/1/

HTML

```
<body>
      <div id="pics" class=""></div>

</body>
```

JS

(function(){

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/spain/media/recent?client_id=c1302f417cda4e09968eaec958fe0ae2",
        success: function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

                $("#pics").append("<img src=" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url+ "/>");
            }
           // console.log(data.data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Open one of the images in a new tab and it shows you what the problem is... http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/3b85c364075d11e3812422000aeb0bcd_5.jpg/

Comment: @Archer of course I know that the access is denied...but why? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a problem with the "/" character...remove it or add an extra space like this:

```
(function(){


         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false,
            url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/malmoefestival/media/recent?client_id=c1302f417cda4e09968eaec958fe0ae2",
            success: function(data) {

                for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

                    $("#pics").append("<img src=" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url+ " />");
                }

            }
        });




    })();
```

Working here: http://jsbin.com/UcUyuQo/1/